# Nginx - how to redirect (301) www to non-www correctly for bot http /https?

Tags: nginx

With the following Nginx config file, I currently can redirect permanently  all HTTP www request to HTTPS non-www .
http://www.example.com =>  https://example;com

All HTTPS non-www request ar well handed ..
https://example.com

But, www HTTPS request are NOT redirected to non-www HTTPS 
https://www.examples.com --> https://www.examples.com
I'ld like to have :
https://www.examples.com --> https://examples.com

what's missing in my config ?
thanks for feedback

default.conf

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
       listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
       server_name example.com;
       include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
       include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

       root /var/www/html;
       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your configuration handles redirecting `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` (but you knew that).

Assuming that your certificate is valid for `www.example.com`, you could create a separate `server` block for port 443 and mark it as a `default_server` (such as you already have for port 80).

In fact you could combine everything that isn't `https://www.example.com` into a single `server` block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  yes, my certificate is valid for bot www and no-www..
I thought about it , but totally forgot to put the snippets onto both blocks ...